# after geb update to 5.1: setting TextArea text fails if not empty previously

Tags: geb

This feels so strange: I am trying to update my dependencies (in preparation for a future update to Java 17):

- groovy from 2.5.14 to 3.0.9
- spock from 1.3-groovy-2.5 to 2.0-groovy-3.0
- and geb from 3.4 to 5.1

Unfortunately some geb tests now fail:
When I try to assign text to a TextArea `someTextarea.text = 'foo'` that works only if the text area has been empty previously.
When it previously contained text, I can watch geb entering the new text in the text area and immediately after that the text vanishes so the text area is now empty.

The same bug happens with geb 5.0.
Any ideas? Something I can try to narrow this down?

Comment: I do not know how urgent this matter is. Chances are that @erdi is going to see this here soon. But you could also ask on the Geb users mailing list. Try to be as specific as possible, e.g. does it happen only in a specific web driver (e.g. for Chrome or FF) or is the behaviour consistent across browsers/drivers? What about Selenium versions? An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce this would also be helpful.

Comment: I cannot think of any reason for that to be happening. Can you also reproduce this on 4.1? Can you please provide an MCVE, ideally as a publicly accessible git repo I could clone and see the problem?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this. When investigating this I learned a lot about our app. It seems to be caused by newer groovy version, not geb or spock. We have a custom, extended navigator that uses groovy meta programming to add behaviour to some navigator methods. With some "modifying methods" we need to wait for ajax requests to be fully handled because JSF needs to do some server magic and partial re-rendering. 
That groovy meta programming broke with groovy 3, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71372255/riddle-me-this-inconsistent-groovy-meta-programming-behaviour