# Riddle me this: Inconsistent groovy meta programming behaviour

Tags: groovy

I stumbled across this when updating a large app from groovy 2 to 3 (and also to corresponding newer spock and geb versions).

This code behaves strange and also a different kind of strange in groovy 2 versus groovy 4.

I *think* we are running without "indy" here. I guess because all the transitive dependencies of our large app bring in specific groovy jars without indy. I should probably goe through them carefully and adapt our gradle build so that only "indy" versions of all jars are picked.

```
class A {
    def foo() {
        bar('hello')
        beep(Optional.of('hello'))
    }

    protected void bar(String value) { println 'A.bar' }
    protected void beep(Optional<String> value) { println 'A.beep' }
}

class B extends A {
    protected void bar(String value) { println 'B.bar' }
    protected void beep(Optional<String> value) { println 'B.beep' }
}

class C extends B implements GroovyInterceptable {
    def invokeMethod(String name, Object args) {
        super."$name"(*args)
    }
}

static void main(String[] args) {
    new C().foo()
    println '---'
    C c = new C()
    c.bar('hello')
    c.beep(Optional.of('hello'))
}
```

Output for groovy 2.5.15:

```
B.bar
A.beep
---
A.bar
A.beep
```

Output for groovy 4.0.0:

```
A.bar
A.beep
---
A.bar
A.beep
```

What I would have expected:

```
B.bar
B.beep
---
B.bar
B.beep
```

What's going on here? Bug or some strange, but expected corner case?

Where is the difference in behavior in between groovy 2 and 4 documented?

In our real app there was a difference already in between groovy 2 and 3 but I have been unable so far to create example code for that.

Is there a way to call the original method inside of invokeMethod? (Can't find anything in the docs, which are very sparse btw.)

Comment: When I test, both groovy 2.5.15 and 3.0.9 print the first output (the one you have for 2.5.15). Only groovy 4.0.0 outputs the second one (the one you have for 3.0.9)

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are right. This example I accidentally tested with groovy 4 versus 2. In our real app, though, there definitely is a "similar difference" when using groovy 2 versus 3. We extend geb's DefaultNavigator and use some meta programming in the subclass. I will fix the question and try to come up with an example for groovy 3 versus 2.

Answer (score 0):

I get your 3.0.9 output for Groovy 2.5.16, 3.0.10 and 4.0.1 -- indy enabled for all three.

Your implementation of `invokeMethod` relies on the behavior of `ScriptBytecodeAdapter#invokeMethodOnSuperN` which is what is behind `super."$name"(*args)`.  When handling "bar" message, the meta-method index has `B.bar(java.lang.String)` for "this" and `B.super$2$bar(java.lang.String)` for "super".  `super$2$bar` is a meta-object protocol (MOP) method that provides the necessary `INVOKESPECIAL` instruction to reach `A#bar(java.lang.String)`.

If you want the output of all calls to be from `B` then you can use `this."$name"(*args)` instead.  In your specific case, there is no need to implement `C` as `GroovyInterceptable` and to try and route "foo", "bar" and "beep" yourself.

Comment: I may be mixing things up, but when I tried `this."$name"(*args)`, I got a stackoverflowerror.

Comment: Oops, bad recommendation.  The interceptor takes effect for a this call.  Not sure off hand how to escape the interceptor and perform a call to `B#bar`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In our real app I have converted from meta programming to manually overriding methods, calling super and adding our custom code. For me the lesson learned is to better shy away from stuff that is "too magic".

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code produce the expected output by making the `B` class compiled statically:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

class A {
    def foo() {
        bar('hello')
        beep(Optional.of('hello'))
    }

    protected void bar(String value) { println 'A.bar' }
    protected void beep(Optional<String> value) { println 'A.beep' }
}

@CompileStatic
class B extends A {
    protected void bar(String value) { println 'B.bar' }
    protected void beep(Optional<String> value) { println 'B.beep' }
}

class C extends B implements GroovyInterceptable {
    def invokeMethod(String name, Object args) {
        super."$name"(*args)
    }
}

static void main(String[] args) {
    new C().foo()
    println '---'
    C c = new C()
    c.bar('hello')
    c.beep(Optional.of('hello'))
}
```

Output:

```
B.bar
B.beep
---
B.bar
B.beep
```

As it was mentioned by [emilies in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71372896/2194470), in the MOP use case scenario something like this happens:

- `c.bar('Hello')`
- `invokeMethod('bar', ['Hello'] as Object[])`
- `super."bar"(['Hello'] as Object[])`

This `super."bar"(['Hello'] as Object[])` is represented by `B.super$2$bar(java.lang.String)` method object which forces `A.bar(java.lang.String)` to be invoked right in the next call frame.

However, if you make the `B` class to be compiled statically, the method that is found to satisfy the `super."bar"(['Hello'] as Object[])` expression, in that case, is `B.bar(java.lang.String)`, and thus it gets invoked directly.

Regarding the differences between Groovy 2.5 and Groovy >=3.0, it looks like you have encountered a compiler bug. The `bar('hello')` inside the `A.foo()` method ignores the MOP and goes directly to `this.bar(java.lang.String)` which in this case is `B.bar(java.lang.String)`.

[image]

It looks like it happens for the `java.lang.String` type (didn't check other types). However, when the type is `java.util.Optional`, then a call like `beep(Optional.of('Hello'))` inside the `A.foo()` method goes through the MOP  and thus it discovers `B.super$2$beep(java.util.Optional)` method to be invoked:

[image]